# Twitter bootstrap modal is opening in front of form

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I'm with a problem with my Twitter bootstrap modal: it's opening in front of my form. I don't have any idea about what I did, because it was working very well 3 days ago. I can write on the form; I think the form is working. The problem is the modal opening in front of the form.

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41175751/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-28%20at%2012.04.11.png]

Comment: Paste some code so we can take a look.

Comment: Seems like a z-index problem, but with no code and no examples it is impossible to say

Comment: My fault, I already fixed it! thanks

Comment: Please post the problem and fix so others can benefit.  I ran into this myself when I had the modal div in my main nav, but seemed to resolve when I moved it out of the nav.

Comment: My problem was I had to put my navbar fixed to top and the modal was opening behind it. I just modified the it and the modal works again

Answer (score 13):

The `.modal-backdrop` class has z-index set to 1040 and the `navbar-fixed-top` has z-index set to 1030. Hence, the backdrop displays over the form.

Override the `.modal-backdrop` z-index value in your CSS file by setting it to a value that is less than the navbar z-index. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: Awesome -- saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 10):

I had similar issues.  I've addressed them here: http://jsfiddle.net/ATeaH/8/

Comment: to summarize this solution, add: $('.modal).appendTo('body'); to your script. This will move the .modal (wherever it was defined) down to where .modal-backdrop is auto-generated by bootstrap, thus making the 2 elements 'siblings', which can correct z-index issues

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution that Nielsen mentioned above which worked for me...

I had the `div` I attach my modal to *inside* the navbar.
I moved the `div` outside the navbar - to just under the `<body>`

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem where a modal was being inserted into the DOM via AJAX.  Without a page refresh, the modal remained behind a the mask and was inaccessible.

Interestingly, the modal worked fine with a page refresh.  Even though I was inserting the modal in the same place with AJAX as it was with HTML, it would not work with AJAX.  My fix was to append the modal partial to the body.  So my code was the following:

```
$('body').append(....j render partial....);
```

I tried some of the other suggestions I came across (like tweaking the `z-index`), but that did not help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. In my case it was due to an unclosed div in my header.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, it worked for me:

```
$('#myModal').appendTo("body").modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with AngularJS and ran into the same issue. To clarify, my modal was in another HTML file that Angular injects into the DOM during runtime through `ng-view`. What caused this problem for me was that I had a css animation class on the div where my ng-view was. As an example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="pageTransition" ng-view></div> <!-- problem: class="pageTransition"-->
</div>
```

Removing the css class fixed the issue and restored my modal to normal working order. A solution around this would be to replace the standard class with Angular's [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). This way, you could dynamically add, modify, or remove a class while using the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `CSS`

```
 .modal-dialog {
    z-index: 1050;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SASS you can do the following inside **_modals.scss**:

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  z-index: $zindex-modal-background; // copy-pasted z-index from .modal-backdrop
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
```